# Loop over array inside object and spit out ids into dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Excuse me if this question has already been answered as I am sure it has but cannot find an example I understand.

What I am trying to accomplish is to loop over and just spit out the ids into a dropdown.

```
const things = {
"list": [{
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "Jack Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": "789101",
        "name": "Ellie Cocks"
    },
    {
        "id": "535253",
        "name": "Peter Johns"
    },
    {
        "id": "9353638",
        "name": "Anna Jacobs"
    }
]}

$.each(things, function() {
    $('#dropdown').append($("<option />").text(things.list.id));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want more data to be added to `option` but this is what you're after.

```js
const select = $('#dropdown');
const things = {
    "list": [{
            "id": "123456",
            "name": "Jack Smith"
        },
        {
            "id": "789101",
            "name": "Ellie Cocks"
        },
        {
            "id": "535253",
            "name": "Peter Johns"
        },
        {
            "id": "9353638",
            "name": "Anna Jacobs"
        }
    ]
}

$.each(things.list, (i, item) => {
    let opt = $("<option />", {
        value: item.id,
        text: item.name
    });
    select.append(opt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

Comment: @JoeHill, you're most welcomed. Please, mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const things = {
"list": [{
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "Jack Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": "789101",
        "name": "Ellie Cocks"
    },
    {
        "id": "535253",
        "name": "Peter Johns"
    },
    {
        "id": "9353638",
        "name": "Anna Jacobs"
    }
]}

things.list.map(function(elem) {
    $('#dropdown').append($('<option/>',{value:elem.id,text:elem.name}));
 });
 
 $(document).on("change","#dropdown",function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO**

```js
const things = {
"list": [{
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "Jack Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": "789101",
        "name": "Ellie Cocks"
    },
    {
        "id": "535253",
        "name": "Peter Johns"
    },
    {
        "id": "9353638",
        "name": "Anna Jacobs"
    }
]}

$.each(things.list, function(val, text) {
    var data = '<option>' + things.list[val].id + '</option>'
    $('select').append(data);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"> 
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let ids = things.list.map(function(item){
    return item.id
});
```

This will work in ES6

Comment: Th OP wants to put ids in dropdown whereas your code just goes through the collection and creates another collection pure of ids. Consider providing question related functionality.